# trying to multiply query results for a total

Tags: php, mysql

### Issue

I've produced a query to determine the total cost per person for a room and the total number of persons in the room; the total cost per person is returning correctly as is the total number of person in the room; however, when I try to echo the minor multiplication for the total, I am merely getting the display of the numbers I wish to multiply.

**For example:**
price per person = $1207
total number of person in the room = 2
query result ... "1207*2" ...

### Question:

I'm certain it is something stupid or minor but could use a second set of eyes.  How do I rewrite the code below to produce the desired result of **$2414**?

### Here's the query:

```
$tourquery = "SELECT t.roomprice, c.totpax 
         FROM clients c, tourprices t 
         WHERE c.roomtype1 = t.roomtype 
         AND c.tourstart = t.tourstart
         AND c.tourbk_id = t.tour_id"; 
$tourresult = $db->query($tourquery); 


while ($roomrate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tourresult))
   {
echo "Per person amount : {$roomrate['roomprice']}<br />";
echo "Total room amount : {$roomrate['roomprice']}*{$roomrate['totpax']}<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```
while ($roomrate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tourresult))
{
    $totalcost = $roomrate['roomprice'] * $roomrate['totpax'];
    echo "Per person amount : {$roomrate['roomprice']}<br />";
    echo "Total room amount : {$totalcost}<br />";
}
```

Comment: Generally, I'm against putting operations inside quotes.  I think it's much clearer to calculate it outside.  Especially when you have the benefit of an editor that gives syntax highlighting.  Try to avoid it if you can.

Comment: Hi Daedalus, I did ... Paddy had answered in 41 seconds of my asking the question and the site doesn't seem to permit acceptance of an answer until 10-minutes after the answer was posted.

Comment: Haha 41 seconds...  That's called "pouncing"!

Comment: @shane I see no speed issue.  Outputting a string is much slower than doing a multiplication.  Beware of coding in a way that sacrifices clarity, and do not optimize prematurely.  I don't know about PHP, but generally you leave the trivial optimizations to the compiler.  In terms of professional coding style, I would always prefer the code that is most descriptive.  If something really needs to be highly optimized, then it ought to have at least as much comments as code (useful comments that say *why* the code is the way it is, *how* it works and *what* it is overcoming).

Comment: Thanks Paddy!  I was concerned a problem would later present.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are outputting a string.  There are a number of way to fix this including the following:

```
while ($roomrate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tourresult))
   {
$total_price = $roomrate['roomprice']*$roomrate['totpax'];
echo "Per person amount : {$roomrate['roomprice']}<br />";
echo "Total room amount : {$total_price}<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also be real fancy and have the math done by mySQL.

```
SELECT t.roomprice, c.totpax, (t.roomprice * c.totpax) AS total_price 
     FROM clients c, tourprices t 
     WHERE c.roomtype1 = t.roomtype 
     AND c.tourstart = t.tourstart
     AND c.tourbk_id = t.tour_id
```

Not sure if you take a performance hit though. I wind up going back and forth on whether to have processing done by the DB or have it done by PHP.